# How can i declare a variable globally so that i can access it across all other viwes in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I need to declare variable globally so that i can use it across all applications.
Basically i want to declare a stack globally so that i can use it across  all views in  my MVC application.

Answer (score 1):

Generally there aren't "global variables" in C#.  However, you can create a `static` member of a class and access it essentially "globally".  For example, suppose you create this in your models:

```
public class GlobalValues
{
    public static string MyValue { get; set; } = "This is globally accessible.";
}
```

Then anywhere in your application you can reference it with:

```
GlobalValues.MyValue
```

So in your view you might simply have:

```
@GlobalValues.MyValue
```

A few things to note would be:

1. If the class is in a namespace not known to the views you can fully-qualify the class name, or add a `@using` directive or modify the application's config to auto-import that namespace into views.
2. If the value has any association with an existing model, it probably belongs on that model.  A `GlobalValues` class here was just for demonstration.  Having a dumping ground of things you don't know where else to put can become a maintenance nightmare quickly in a codebase.
3. A `string` is of course just an example here.  Your property can be any type you like.  If it's fairly complex and needs more initialization logic, a [static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) would be where you put that logic.